# ¿Cómo cambiar flex-flow en diseño para móvil?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Tengo 3 contenedores, un main y dentro de él un left y un right. *¿Cómo puedo usar las propiedades de `flexbox` para que cuando mi web sea vista en una PC el modo sea `row nowrap`, y cuando este en móvil sea `row wrap` o en columnas?*

Es decir, que al ver la página en una PC se vean horizontalmente los dos elementos y al verla en un móvil se vean los dos elementos verticalmente, arriba el left y abajo el right.

Ahora mismo, con el actual código, puedo ver la pantalla tal y como la quiero en PC, pero no se como adaptarla...

HTML:

```
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="left-container">
    <img class="img-control" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/hXMhw95MCOHGiNLkJi6K0fQz-a-syFJwepaFBdW3ZzUdWRB_gWZOnNjpxPHbWc8QG2o76UHtXwVsNYshcSi5HkayDKjsVIqnEOWzFOogeNoRtTEaGg7kkWWyyvk">
  </div>

  <div id="form-container"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  background-color:green;
}

#left-container{
  padding-left:2em;
  padding-right:2em;
  width:50%;
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column;
  background-color:white;
  justify-content:center;
}

.img-control{
  height: auto;
  width: 70%; 
  align-self:center;
 
}

#form-container{
  width:50%;
}
```

Agradezco mucho la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

No tiene caso declarar que el contenedor padre tenga un **`flex-direction`** con un valor de **`row`** pues ese es el calor que tiene por defecto entonces *ponerlo o no, no causa diferencia*.

Por otro lado en el contenedor padre solo deberías agregar la siguiente propiedad y valor para que la distribución horizontal sea uniforme:

```
justify-content: space-around;
```

Ahora para la duda principal, tienes opciones como:

- Establece por medio de *media-queries* cuando la dimensión sea igual a algún valor específico, entonces al elemento padre acomode a sus elementos hijos en columna de esta forma:

---

```
@media screen and (max-width: algun-valorpx) {
    .elemento-padre {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

O tal vez de forma mas simple, indicando que los elementos pueden fluir entre distintas filas<sup>1</sup>

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

**Fuentes consultadas**

- <sup>1</sup>[flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)